# IIS 8 Service Name - Windows Server 2012

Tags: iis, windows, windows-server-2012, windows-service

I wrote a monitoring app which probes different parts of the system. Now I look for IIASADMIN service to see status of IIS. But there is not a service named IISADMIN there.

What's the service name of IIS on Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 10):

You should monitor the `Windows Process Activation Service` and the `World Wide Web Publishing Service`.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732050(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The IISAdmin service no longer exists for IIS7 and above. You might want to monitor the new WAS service instead (I'm not implying that WAS is what IISAdmin used to be).

Look at the [Inroduction to IIS Architecture](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture) for more info.

Comment: This is incorrect the service does exist but is not installed by default. The IIS Admin Service is part of the IIS 6 Management Compatibility features. It still exists but is not necessary for IIS to operate. It is only necessary when working with applications (typically installers for older software) that expect to access the IIS 6 Metabase.